# How do I edit an existing ArcGIS .lyr file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, editing

I have downloaded a layer file. The layer names are long, and I want to change these to approved abbreviations, for ease of data input.  For instance, the layer file values look like this:

A1.1.1 Broadleaved woodland - natural.

A1.1.2 Broadleaved woodland - plantation

I want my students just to be able to use A1.1.1, A1.1.2 etc as the values. Is there a way of editing these files?

Comment: Yes of course you can edit the attributes of the table.  What software are you using?  When you say layer, do you mean a shapefile or a featureclass, or an actual .lyr file?

Comment: Maybe see these articles: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-attributes/about-editing-attributes.htm , http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/understanding-how-to-edit-values-in-a-table.htm , http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Editing%20values%20in%20a%20table , http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011516

Comment: Can you please clarify?  What exactly are you talking about?  Maybe some screenshots will help.

Answer (score 3):

if you are in ArcMAP, right click on the layer, select properties, select the GENERAL tab, and change the layer name.  Then save as .lyr file overwriting previous one.